# What to do if there are two tablespace directories after pg_upgrade using hard-links option

Tags: postgresql, tablespace, pg-upgrade

A while back, I ran a PostgreSQL pg_upgrade on a PG11 database, to PG12, which has a tablespace located at /ssd in it.

I used the --link option in my command to create hard links, as to not double up the space as it is a huge database.

Unfortunately, I did not remove the old cluster after the upgrade.

A few months have passed since then, and we wanted to upgrade to PG15 now, but I noticed that inside /ssd, both PG_11_201809051 and PG_12_201909212 were still being used, with very recent modification dates on certain files in both directories.

When checking presence of files, I noticed there are some files in PG_11_201809051 that aren't in PG_12_201909212 and vice versa.

So, my question is: If I upgrade now to PG15, will it safely take all that's required from both of those directories, and move it all into a new PG_15 directory in /ssd?

If not, what options do I have to ensure a successful upgrade, and removal of old clusters?

Tried:  Ran a PostgreSQL upgrade from PG11 to PG12.

Expected result: Nothing from PG11 would be used anymore.

Actual Result: PG_11_201809051 is still being used alongside PG_12_201909212  within the /ssd directory

Postgres config for tablespace:

```
temp_tablespaces = 'ssd'
```

Tablespace was initially created like so:

```
CREATE TABLESPACE ssd OWNER postgres LOCATION '/ssd';
```

```
$ ls -lh /data/pg12/pg_tblspc/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 postgres postgres 4 Jun 16  2023 16412 -> /ssd


$ ls -lh /ssd/
total 0
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres  6 Mar  6  2021 lost+found
drwx------. 4 postgres postgres 36 May 26  2023 PG_11_201809051
drwx------. 4 postgres postgres 36 Jun 17  2023 PG_12_201909212
```

```
 $ tree -d /ssd  
/ssd
 ├── lost+found
 ├── PG_11_201809051
 │   ├── 16420
 │   └── pgsql_tmp
 └── PG_12_201909212
     ├── 16414
     └── pgsql_tmp
```

Comment: By "tablespace" do you mean an explicit table-space, or is this just a directory? Sharing a dump of your database directory structure with `tree -d /ssd` might be useful.

Comment: I have copied the tree into your main question + formatted it. Have I got it laid out correctly?

Comment: Perfect yes. Sorry, I am new to Stack Overflow :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably better off exploring this on the mailing list or in a chatroom - a lot depends on the details.

It looks to me like you might just have not unlinked the old installation after the changeover. This is the final step in the pg_upgrade instructions and can be easily missed. ("16. Delete old cluster").

Let me show you a little example with hardlinks:

```
$ date > foo
$ date > bar
$ ln bar baz
$ ls -l
total 12
-rw-rw-r-- 2 richard richard 29 Mar  8 08:28 bar
-rw-rw-r-- 2 richard richard 29 Mar  8 08:28 baz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 richard richard 29 Mar  8 08:28 foo
# wait for a couple of minutes...
$ date > bar
$ ls -l
total 12
-rw-rw-r-- 2 richard richard 29 Mar  8 08:29 bar
-rw-rw-r-- 2 richard richard 29 Mar  8 08:29 baz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 richard richard 29 Mar  8 08:28 foo
```

You can see the "2" for the linked files and "1" for a file that has no links to it. Also the timestamps are linked because they are actually the same file.

So - check the link number on those maybe-duplicated tablespace files and also check what `stat` has to say about them. If they are indeed copies you should be safe to `unlink` them.

You may also have old linked files in somewhere like `/var/lib/postgresql/12/...` (location will depend on your setup).

NOTE: Personally I would stop postgresql and take a full filesystem backup of all of its files before doing that. It depends how much data you have, how important it is, recent backup availability etc.

Comment: I will give this a try. Thanks very much! Appreciate it